# cytoscape.js webgl renderer

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js, webgl, cytoscape.js

I am trying to write a layout extension and have already looked at the examples provided both from the existing extensions (e.g. arbor, cola, cose-bilkent, etc.) and the scaffolding [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/slush-cytoscape-extension/blob/master/templates/cytoscape-ext.js).  The place where I am hung up is with the webGL renderer.  In all of the examples, this is handled by the core (for canvas), if I am not mistaken.  Is it possible to use a webGL renderer through three.js?  If so, is it as simple as just creating/attaching the required webGL elements in the extension (e.g. scene, cameras, light-sources, etc.)?

The reason for the webGL push is that I want to implement a 3D adjacency matrix (I cannot remember where I found the paper, but someone had implemented this in a desktop application with subject, predicate, and object being the X,Y, and Z axes) and don't see another way to do that efficiently for large result sets on the order of 10-25K nodes/edges.

Comment: have you gotten anywhere with this WebGL renderer?

Comment: Maybe you can take suggestions from https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cytoscape supports multiple renderers, but it does not support 3D co-ordinates.  Positions are defined as (x, y).

You could add a 3D renderer if you like, but you'd have to use a data property for the z position, because the position object doesn't support z.

It's a lot of work to write a renderer, especially one that's performant and fully-featured.  If you were to write a 2D renderer, you could reuse all the existing hittests, gestures/interaction, events, etc -- so you could focus on drawing tech.  To write a 3D renderer, you'll have to do all the rendering logic from scratch.

If your data requires 3D (e.g. representing 3D atomic bonds or 3D protein structures), then writing a 3D renderer may be a good idea.  If it's just to have a neat 3D effect, it's probably not worth it -- as 3D is much harder for users to navigate and understand.

Comment: Fair enough.  The layout I am after is a 3D adjacency matrix, which puts the subject, predicate, and object on the X, Y, and Z axes respectively.  Unfortunately, it's not just eye-candy...which, I agree is not worth the effort.  But, for this, I will make the time...though it may be a while to get it done.  If the target is WebGL through Three.js, is there a pointer somewhere to get me started on the right foot?

Comment: You could take a look at / fork the default renderer, since you'll have to duplicate a lot of its basic things, like receiving notifications.

Comment: how "Cytoscape.js supports multiple renderers"? It doesn't say such thing in docs @maxkfranz